# Can I automate a loop query based on category with the page's title?

Tags: wordpress

To explain further, I need to get a page to display posts from a specific category. I want to automate this process so I don't have to make a template for each category. How would I do that? (keep in mind the person I'm building this is for has no coding experience.)

The only way I could think off from the top of my head is to use the title or slug. So if the category is named the same thing as the slug, could I filter by category using the slug? Maybe this isn't the best way... what should I do?

This is what I came up with, but it doesn't work, I'm sure due to improper use on may part, but I've been pouring over the WP codex and Google with no avail to tell me my problem.

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args= array(
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'category_name' => echo the_title('\'','\'',)
);
query_posts($args);
?>
```

Comment: I whink i don't get what you want.. Aren't you using category.php? If so, why not check by current category ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up working:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$page_slug = $post->post_name;
$args= array(
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'paged' => $paged
);
query_posts($args);
query_posts( 'category_name=' . $page_slug );
?>
```

for those of you with the same question.